# Config webpack to pick jquery.min.js instead of jquery.js from node_modules

Tags: npm, webpack

Is there any way to tell webpack to pick `jquery.min.js` instead of `jquery.js` from the `node_modules/jquery` folder when creating the `bundle.js` file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. When you include `jquery` into a module with

```
require('jquery');
```

Webpack looks for the file in the `main` section of `node_modules/jquery/package.json` and includes it. You can use the relative path in require:

```
require('jquery/dist/jquery.min');
```

to directly include the needed file instead.

Comment: I don't like relative path approach!! I tried modifying main section as "dist/jquery.min.js" and it worked, great